# jQuery $.ajax error in Firefox: "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0"

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I figured this issue out already, but I'm posting here since it might be useful to others.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    var newRow = $(data).hide();
    newRow.slideDown();    
});
```

My the ajax response looks something like this:

```
<li class="clearfix">
  <!-- snip -->
</li>
<li class="dock-row">
  <!-- snip -->
</li>
```

The line that gives the error is:

```
var newRow = $(data).hide();
```

Comment: Are you *certain* that your response looks like that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the data to the page first:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('<div id="myid" style="display:none;"></div>').prependTo($('body'));
    $('#myid').html(data)
    $('#myid').slideDown();    
});
```

**Update after first comment**

Your code is equivalent to doing something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    var newRow = $('<li class="clearfix">\r\n<!-- snip -->\]r\n</li>\r\n<li class="dock-row">\r\n<!-- snip -->\r\n</li>').hide();
    newRow.slideDown();    
});
```

Just because FF doesn't throw an exception doesn't mean the code is correct.

Comment: Well I don't know that that's really true. I don't get any errors from Firefox when I do a test with HTML that looks like what's in the original question. It shouldn't be necessary to add it to the DOM just to set its style to "display: none".

Comment: Yes, you're right. Would be nice if the question was more specific. I'm sure Mike will answer it himself.

Comment: I only tried it because I suspected there might be an issue with the "naked" `<li>` elements, but my Firefox didn't complain.

Comment: No, we bring in naked li's via ajax in our app, then append them to an existing ul. That would suck if Firefox prevented it.

Comment: It wasn't so much the importing of them that I thought might be a problem, but the under-the-covers work that jQuery does to make that "$(data)" work - that is, dropping them into a document fragment by themselves without a surrounding `<u>`.  Completely moot of course since there's no error :-)